# Issue with addEventListener & target clic in my website

Tags: javascript, html, click, addeventlistener

I'm playing around with HTML, CSS & JavaScript but I'm not very good. I'm trying the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("MYCLASS");
for(var i = 0, j=tab.length; i<j; i++){
tab[i].addEventListener('click', afficher,false);
}
function afficher(){
alert(this.class);
}
</script>
```

Attaching the click listener on all my `.MYCLASS` `div`s is working. However, on Google Chrome in the alert window it throws me `undefined` instead of `.MYCLASS`.

So I tried this code as alternative:

```
function afficher(e){
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
  alert(target.class);
}
```

But the result is exactly the same. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there's no property defined for a `html` DOM object named `class`.

If you want to get the class value, you should use `this.className`.

So your function should look like this:

```
function afficher(){
    alert(this.className);
}
```

Comment: Oh thx man ;) I'm gonna try changing the style (display="none") of my divs now. You rock

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple 'for in' loop, but you need to be sure that you are appending events to only DOM elements. The HTML list that is returned by getElementsByClassName() isn't only returning DOM elements.

```js
var tab = document.getElementsByClassName("MYCLASS");

for(var i in tab){

  // you need this check to filter anything that isn't a DOM element
  if(typeof tab[i] ==="object"){
    tab[i].addEventListener('click', afficher,false);
  }

}

function afficher(){
  alert(this.className);
}
```